# New Page UIButton Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Hello I´m going to made an App with lots of ViewController in Swift, but I don´t know how it works.
I start like this

`func SpielAufZeitStarten(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard (name:"SpielAufZeit",bundle:nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as ViewController
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)         .window?.rootViewController = vc 
}`

But this is only between Storyboards i hope you find a way to jump between ViewController and not between Storyboards.
Thanks for your help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigation controller. In storyboard create a ViewController, then select it, and then go to Editor->Embed in->Navigation controller

After this, you are able to add more view controllers, like this:

[image]

All I did is, I added a button, then I Control-clicked and draged it to the next view controller. After that you just select "push", and youre done!